# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'run'

Tags: tensorflow

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


a3dim = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],
                  [[5,6],[7,8]]
                 ])

print("a3dim Shape: ", a3dim.shape)

tf_t=tf.convert_to_tensor(a3dim,dtype=tf.float64)

print('tf_t : ',tf_t)
print('tf_t[0][0][0] : ',tf_t[0][0][0])
print('tf_t[1][1][1] : ',tf_t[1][1][1])

print('run(tf_t) : \n', tf.run(tf_t))
```

When I run this program, I have the following error:

**Error:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-3506c45f6784> in <module>()
     15 print('tf_t[1][1][1] : ',tf_t[1][1][1])
     16 
---> 17 print('run(tf_t) : \n', tf.run(tf_t))

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'run'
```

How do I solve this tensorflow issue?
Is it a version problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


a3dim = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],
                  [[5,6],[7,8]]
                 ])

print("a3dim Shape: ", a3dim.shape)

tf_t=tf.convert_to_tensor(a3dim,dtype=tf.float64)

print('tf_t : ',tf_t)
print('tf_t[0][0][0] : ',tf_t[0][0][0])
print('tf_t[1][1][1] : ',tf_t[1][1][1])
sess=tf.Session()#create session
print('run(tf_t) : \n', sess.run(tf_t))
sess.close()#close session
```

Tensorflow needs graph and Session to compute. The first step of the startup graph is to create a Session object. If there are no creation parameters, the Session builder will start the default graph. Session manages all resources of the TensorFlow program runtime. The Session needs to be closed after all calculations are completed to help the system recycle resources, otherwise the problem of resource leakage may occur.

Answer (score 1):

you have to first create a session to run  `tf_t` then something like `session.run(tf_t)` would work.

Comment: added with tf_t.Session() as tfs
print('run(tf_t) : \n', tfs.run(tf_t))  I have now as error: File "<ipython-input-34-19330f20e031>", line 17
    with tf_t.Session() as tfs
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax